# What is the difference between Freidman mse and mse?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, decision-trees

The original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55113978/what-is-the-difference-between-freidman-mse-and-mse) was posted on StackOverflow. However, taking into account the recommendations of Sergey Bushmanov, I'm providing an answer through this medium.

Answer (score 4):

As Sergey has pointed out on the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55113978/what-is-the-difference-between-freidman-mse-and-mse) question, going through the following [link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_criterion.pyx) one finds the reference to the [original](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/trebst.pdf) article. So, we're going to proced by unraveling the components of each formula (explaining each of them) and then doing a proper interpretation of the splitting criterion that Jerome Friedmann proposed.

#### 1. Probabilities $p_{k}$

First, let's consider 
\begin{align}
    p_{k} = exp(F_{k}(x)) / \sum_{l = 1} ^{K} \exp(F_{l}(x)),
\end{align}

where $F(x)$ is a logistic transformation. The term $p_{k}$ determine an exponential way to consider probabilities to belong to a particular $k$ class, that gives a mayor probability to the events that are more likely to happen and a lesser probability to the ones that are less likely to happen. For example, consider that the values that $F(x)$ could take are 1, 7 and 49, thus

\begin{align}
     \frac{\exp(49)}{\exp(1) + \exp(7) + \exp(49)} \approx .9999 > \frac{\exp(7)}{\exp(1) + \exp(7) + \exp(49)} \approx 0.
\end{align}

In other words, greater values of $F(x)$ are more likely to happen.

#### 2. Weights $w_{l}$

Once we know that $p_{k} \in [0,1)$, we arrive at the definition of the weights

\begin{align}
    w_{l}  = \sum_{i \in R_{l}} w_{l}(x_{i}) = \sum_{i \in R_{l}}p_{k}(x_{i})(1 - p_{k}(x_{i})),
\end{align}
for the $x$'s in the region $R_{l}$. In the other words, the weights are the sum of the probabilities, that in the given region $l$, every $x_{i}$ belongs to a certain $k$-class. This is fundamental to understand the criteron proposed by Friedman, as we would see next.

#### 3. Least-Squares Improvement Criterion

The least-squares improvement criterion is

\begin{align}
      i^2(R_{l}, R_{r}) = \frac{w_{l}w_{r}}{w_{l} + w_{r}}(\overline{y_{l}}-\overline{y_{r}})^2  \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:(1),
\end{align}

considering the fact that we would like to split the current region $R$ into two subregions $(R_{l}, R_{r})$. Remember that at the end we would like to do the split as clean as possible, that is to say, the outcomes are close to the average outcome of all $k$ cases at that node. Therefore, **this splitting criterion allow us to take the decision not only on how close we're to the desired outcome, but also based on the probabilities of the desired $k$-class that we're going to find in the region $l$ or in the region $r$**.

Disclaimer: This is what I understood by reading the original paper by Friedman, any errors should be pointed out. Thanks

Comment: I was going to create a custom splitter that was focused on differences in the node means when I saw the FriedmanMSE criterion (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_criterion.pyx).  For a pure comparison of means, I'd think the `proxy_impurity_improvement` method would just calculate the absolute value of `diff`.  Given that the calculation is more complicated, there must be a different intent, right?  I don't follow how the probability discussion in your answer relates to what appears to be a weighted comparison of means for regression.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm also getting very similar results when using FriedmanMSE instead of regular MSE.

Comment: Scikit-learn's implementation uses the Friedman's improvement criterion for MSE only in regression trees, but the paper and you talk about probabilities of a certain class **k**, i.e., classification. There seem to be some differences between the two approaches...